# How to derive the set notation from regular expressions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, regular-language

I have a language $L$ with some context-free grammer which generates the following strings:

```
def
dededefff
dedeff
dedededeffff
dededededefffff
```

Im trying to come up with some set definition of that example, however struggle to finde the appropriate set:

$L = \{(d,e,f)\ |\ d\in L\wedge e\in L\wedge f \in L\}$

Where:

```
S → DESF | DEF
D → d
E → e
F → f
```

is  K and

$G = (\{S, D, E, F\}, \{d, e,f\}, K, S)$ the context free grammer

Comment: The task is not so easy... Of course, if you are looking at a *finite* number of stings, you can simply list them all: $L = \{ s \mid s= st_1 \lor s=st_2 \lor \ldots \lor s=st_n \}$. But thi will not do with an ulimited list.

Comment: The issue is that with the set notation we hane no easy way to formalize "repetitions", like "$dede...$"

Comment: Why not the usual "syntax" for [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) ?

Comment: Hi @MauroALLEGRANZA, thank you for your comments. Unfortunately I have to provide some set notation.

Comment: What is the context-free grammer ?

Comment: Hi @QthePlatypus, I edited the question, sry completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following:
$$\{(de)^nf^n\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

Comment: Hi @quasi, thx you for the answer. Im not 100% but the string `deff` is inlcuded as well? since it would violate the grammer

Comment: @Mamba: No, the exponents must be the same, so $deff$ is not in the set, since that would have the form $(de)^1f^2$.